# Battlefield play4free on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: games

I have for a week ubuntu 14.04 on my pc. It works great, it's easy and fast. But now comes the problem.

I would like to play battlefield play4free on ubuntu. I know, I must do this with wine and PLayOnlinux. I have installed battlefield play4free on my pc via firefox,till then everything was OK.

But when I want to launch the game I get a black screen with the tekst whe detected an serious problem. and thats it.Then my game shut down and then happens nothing.What is the problem of this and how can i fix this?

Comment: **Then my game shut down and then happens nothing.What is the problem of this and how can i fix this? **  Lauch it from command line and edit into the question errors you see.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following mentioned to get BF running:

- You need playonlinux 4.2+, wine 1.5.26, [mono 2.10](http://wiki.winehq.org/Mono) (not 3.0).
- Visual C++ 2008; you install that with "winetricks"
- Enable GLSL from display settings (intel only?).

But 1 thing that might be a problem:

- BF uses [Punkbuster](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=5813). From the comments and the [petition](http://www.petitionspot.com/petitions/PunkBusterforWINE):

> We're sorry, but Wine and other compatibility layers are not supported. Punkbuster uses advanced and rare Windows functions, which are subject of change quite often. Unfortunately these programs are not in such a end state of development that it will be able to support all of Punkbuster's functions.

[This might help](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23058) in getting BF running but [this](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=10561) talks about punkbuster not working and you need it to run BF.

---

I would advice to not use WINE and install virtualbox and a Windows in it. That way you can install Windows software and the Windows version of BF. That will work and will work a lot smoother.

Comment: thanks I will give it a try, but one question where can I install the mono for linux?

Comment: see my edit @Brianwk

Comment: well there are 2 problems..

I can't install: VisualC++2008 because my os is 64bits
and I can't install the mono for a unknown reason...

Comment: That is a pity. I do believe you are better off using virtualbox and Windows in that ;)